# Align ordered list number to first row of content

Tags: html, css

I have an ordered list that can contain any number of elements. Each element can be different in size, but regardless of size I want the number of the ordered list to align with the first row of the content. So what I want to achieve is this:

1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...
2. Box 1

See my jsfiddle for the problem I have.

https://jsfiddle.net/txo5bsua/2/

This is the HTML and CSS I have

```css
.boxes {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.box {
  display: table-cell;
}

.box1 {
  background: orange;
  width: 75%;
}

.box2 {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <div class="boxes">
      <div class="box box1">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi quis condimentum massa. Quisque purus nisl, finibus id placerat id, ultricies non magna. Sed justo dui, tristique et metus at, fringilla viverra ipsum. Duis malesuada est eget lectus fermentum,
        vitae pretium eros tempor. Integer eu mi metus. Cras dui ipsum, iaculis ut libero dictum, dapibus consequat orci. Sed semper vitae lorem eu sollicitudin. Curabitur dapibus fringilla facilisis. Nullam facilisis ante in velit maximus gravida.
      </div>
      <div class="box box2">
        <input type="radio">Yes
        <input type="radio">No
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="boxes">
      <div class="box box1">Box 1</div>
      <div class="box box2">Box 2</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Do you still want a gap between .boxes?

Comment: (Interesting: I think the content is rendering in exactly the manner you desire on *Firefox*. On Google Chrome and on Safari, I am seeing a line break after the number of the ordered list before the content begins. So I take it that your goal is to get rid of the visual line break in all browsers, right?)

Comment: change display:table to display:inline-flex in class .boxes

Comment: @chirag changing table to inline-flex makes the top of the content line up, but it also causes the vertical line dividing the two columns to vary when you go from the first row to the second one... (Or at least that's what I observed; I'm going to compare my fiddle with what you posted in your answer now...)

Comment: (The problem with the width of the cells varying between the rows might only come up when the browser width is sufficiently narrow, but it does arise for me with @chirag's jsfiddle...)

Comment: I compared the result on Chrome with what I get on IE and it's a big difference. I didn't think to check that. 
@ovokuro I'm not really sure what gap you are talking about. I just would like the number to start on the same row as the text in the box.

Comment: @pnkfelix Yes, no visual line break in any browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```css
.boxes {
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
}
li {
  clear: both;
}

.box {
    display: table-cell;
 }

 .box1 {
     background: orange;
     width:75%;
  }

  .box2 {
      background: yellow;
   }
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>
        <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box box1">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi quis condimentum massa. Quisque purus nisl, finibus id placerat id, ultricies non magna. Sed justo dui, tristique et metus at, fringilla viverra ipsum. Duis malesuada est eget lectus fermentum, vitae pretium eros tempor. Integer eu mi metus. Cras dui ipsum, iaculis ut libero dictum, dapibus consequat orci. Sed semper vitae lorem eu sollicitudin. Curabitur dapibus fringilla facilisis. Nullam facilisis ante in velit maximus gravida.
            </div>
            <div class="box box2">
               <input type="radio">Yes
               <input type="radio">No
            </div>
        </div>  
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box box1">Box 1</div>
            <div class="box box2">Box 2</div>
        </div>  
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: (for others who are curious about what the diff is here versus the original code: Mers added a `float: right` to `.boxes`, and added a `li { clear: both }`. Apparently both changes are necessary; if you leave out the `li { clear: both }`, both of the two numbers end up at the top of the table.)

Comment: This solved my issue both in Chrome and in IE! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

updated answer. it will work on IE also

use **display:inline-table**

demo: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/txo5bsua/4/)

```css
.boxes {
  display:inline-table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.box {
  display: table-cell;
}

.box1 {
  background: orange;
  width:75%;
}

.box2 {
  background: yellow;
  width:25%;
}
```

```html
<ol>
<li>
<div class="boxes">
   <div class="box box1">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi quis condimentum massa. Quisque purus nisl, finibus id placerat id, ultricies non magna. Sed justo dui, tristique et metus at, fringilla viverra ipsum. Duis malesuada est eget lectus fermentum, vitae pretium eros tempor. Integer eu mi metus. Cras dui ipsum, iaculis ut libero dictum, dapibus consequat orci. Sed semper vitae lorem eu sollicitudin. Curabitur dapibus fringilla facilisis. Nullam facilisis ante in velit maximus gravida.
 </div>
   <div class="box box2">
     <input type="radio">Yes
     <input type="radio">No
   </div>
</div>  
</li>
<li>
<div class="boxes">
   <div class="box box1">Box 1</div>
   <div class="box box2">Box 2</div>
</div>  
</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: This works great in Chrome, but unfortunately doesn't work as well in IE. The list item number appears in the bottom left corner instead of in the upper left corner.

Comment: i have updated my answer. it will work on IE also.you can check it

Comment: I can confirm that it is now working in IE. I am currently still running with @Mers solution, but if I get any problems I will try this solution.

Answer (score 0):

use `display: inline-flex;` instead of `display: table;` for your class `.boxes`.

If you want to keep the space below the boxes you can add `margin-bottom: 20px;`:

```css
.boxes {
  display:inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.box {
  display: table-cell;
}

.box1 {
  background: orange;
  width:75%;
}

.box2 {
  background: yellow;
  width: 25%;
}

li {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<ol>
<li>
<div class="boxes">
   <div class="box box1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi quis condimentum massa. Quisque purus nisl, finibus id placerat id, ultricies non magna. Sed justo dui, tristique et metus at, fringilla viverra ipsum. Duis malesuada est eget lectus fermentum, vitae pretium eros tempor. Integer eu mi metus. Cras dui ipsum, iaculis ut libero dictum, dapibus consequat orci. Sed semper vitae lorem eu sollicitudin. Curabitur dapibus fringilla facilisis. Nullam facilisis ante in velit maximus gravida.
 </div>
   <div class="box box2">
     <input type="radio">Yes
     <input type="radio">No
   </div>
</div>  
</li>
<li>
<div class="boxes">
   <div class="box box1">Box 1</div>
   <div class="box box2">Box 2</div>
</div>  
</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: This works great in Chrome, but unfortunately doesn't work as well in IE. The list item number appears in the bottom left corner instead of in the upper left corner.